# Animation not exported to COLLADA

Tags: animation, collada

I have a model consisting of 4 meshes: 'base' and 3 'electron'.
electrons are quads with a transparent electron texture. Both 3, have an animation of quad rotation.
When I export to COLLADA, object exported, but without animation.

PS: I guess Blender export to COLLADA is crippled. Is there any other tool which loads .blend and exports .dae, with better COLLADA support?

Comment: Why not use FBX?

Comment: Because I am hobbyist and I use open technologies.
I made the assumption that because COLLADA is open, open software like Blender support it 100%.
No. This assumption was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Blender's collada export is indeed in a delicate state to say the least. I am not sure about exporting animations as collada, but I can say for sure that nothing in this world besides Blender can open .blend files. They are basically brain dumps. Trying another format could be your best strategy.